# storing different languages in sql table

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL server management, creating tables for a glossary for example where you will need different translations for different words .. i am storing 15 different languages such as french, italian, spanish .. but when storing these in a table theyre are outputted fine, but when creating a table valued function they dont output correctly. my return is a simple select and for Bulgarian it just outputs question marks

Is there any way to help sql management to read these languages better?

appreciate the help

[image: DATABASE STRUCTURE]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].SelectExportObject ( @TITLE NVARCHAR(MAX) ) 
RETURNS @Result TABLE
( 
  BG                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  CS                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  DE                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  EL                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  EN                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  ES                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  ET                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  FI                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  FR                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  GA                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  HU                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  IT                NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  LT                NVARCHAR(MAX) 
 )

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @BG VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @CS VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @DE VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @EL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @EN VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ES VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ET VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @FI VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @FR VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @GA VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @HU VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @IT VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @LT VARCHAR(MAX)


    select  @BG = c.BG,
           @CS = c.CS, 
           @DE = c.DE, 
           @EL = c.EL, 
           @EN = c.EN, 
           @ES = c.ES, 
           @ET = c.ET, 
           @FI = c.FI, 
           @FR = c.FR, 
           @GA = c.GA,
           @HU = c.HU,
           @IT = c.IT,  
           @LT = c.LT
    from tblTEST c where c.title = @Title


    /* Populate the values of @Str1 and @Str2 how ever you need to */

 INSERT INTO @Result (BG,CS,DE,EL,EN,ES,ET,FI,FR,GA,HU,IT,LT)
 VALUES (@BG,@CS,@DE,@EL,@EN,@ES,@ET,@FI,@FR,@GA,@HU,@IT,@LT)

    RETURN;
END
```

Comment: Possibly sounds like you have unicode characters, but are using a `varchar`. We don't have any SQL, sample data, or anything to go on here, so this is all guess work. You need to expand you question to show examples, etc. Here's a good place to start: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/

Comment: @Larnu - I have included an image of my table structure .. if i do a simple select * from the table - the output is correct. but my function to return a table just returns '?????'

Comment: Images are awful things when asking T-SQL questions, we can't interact with it; post your DDL as **text**. You've also forgotten to include the T-SQL for your function, as well as an `INSERT` statement for your sample data.

Comment: Are you using stored Procedure Or Inline Query to get the Data from Database?

Comment: @Larnu - apologies, i have added my function to the question

Comment: Your variables are declared an a `varchar`.

Comment: @MuhamedShafeeq i am using a table valued function

Comment: You're declaring your variables as `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR` in your TVF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for this to be a multi line table-value function, it'll perform much worse than an inline table-value function.

The problem you have is that you have declared your variables as a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`, however, if we change it to a inline table-value function, then the problem doesn't even exist (as those variables disappear):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].SelectExportObject ( @Title nvarchar(MAX) ) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS

    SELECT t.BG,
           t.CS, 
           t.DE, 
           t.EL, 
           t.EN, 
           t.ES, 
           t.ET, 
           t.FI, 
           t.FR, 
           t.GA,
           t.HU,
           t.IT,  
           t.LT
    FROM tblTEST t
    WHERE t.title = @Title;

GO
```